# Amazon AWS S3 OAI access control

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket called 'mybucket' which is fronted with a cloudfront distribution. I have configured a cloudfront Origin Access Identity (OAI) and set the bucket policy as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So now when I request a file via cloudfront, it works as expected and serves files, but direct access via S3 is prevented. Awesome.

My problem is that this bucket policy only applies to new/freshly uploaded files and not the existing files in the bucket. I would have thought the policy at the bucket level would be applied to all files? Do I need to re-upload everything in my bucket or is there a way to push this new bucket policy to all existing objects?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 bucket policies are **evaluated at the time that the request is received**. Therefore, it applies to the bucket immediately when the policy is applied (well, it actually takes a few seconds to activate).

You do *not* need to re-upload files.

It is possible that **your web browser has cached files** prior to creating the bucket policy. Test this by trying to access the files from a different browser or different computer.

It is also possible that certain **objects in your bucket have Permissions settings at the object level**. For any objects that are accessible directly, check the Permissions settings and ensure there are not settings for `Everyone`.